# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]:

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Dusculpen mi ignorancia en el tema, pero por razones de version de servidor solo debo trabajar con ECS5, todo el proceso lo hace bien pero al final me sale el error de encabezado, aca el codigo si alguien puede ver el error por favor:

```
return listaPromociones.reduce(function (sequence, usuario) {
                return sequence.then(function () {
                    return actualizaTodo(usuario);
                }).then(function () {
                    console.log("registro actualizado ", JSON.stringify(usuario))
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    console.log("err   ..  ", err)
                    res.status(400).json({ message: "ocurrio un problema al actualizar " })
                })

            }, Promise.resolve())
                .then(function (err,salida) {
                    if (err) res.status(400).send({  err }); 
                     res.status(200).json({ message: "ok" })
                   
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log("err   ..  ", err)
                    res.status(400).json({ message: "ocurrio un problema al actualizar " })
                })
```

disculpen los errores, pero estoy comenzando..

aqui el metodo que llamo, (todas las llaves estan completas):

```
 var actualizaTodo = function (elemento) {
                return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    TransbankAcuerdos.updateOne({ _id: elemento.idAcuerdo }, { $set: { producto_id: elemento.idProductoOriginal } }, function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log("ocurrio un error")
                            reject('ocurrio un problema intentalo nuevamente')
                        } else  {
                            
                            console.log("actualizo acuerdo " , elemento.idAcuerdo)
                           
                            User.updateOne({ _id: elemento.iduser }, { $pull: { propiedades: { promociones: { activo:true } } } }, function (err ) {

                                if (err) { 
                                    console.log("ocurrio un error")
                                    reject('ocurrio un problema intentalo nuevamente')
                                }
                                else  {
                                 
                                    console.log("actualizo usuario " , elemento.iduser)
                                 
                                    Promociones.updateOne({ _id: elemento.idPromo }, { $set: { estado: false } }, function (err) {
                                        if (err) {
                                            console.log("ocurrio un error")
                                            reject('ocurrio un problema intentalo nuevamente')
                                        } else  {
                                            console.log("actualizo promociones " , elemento.idPromo)
                                            resolve();

                                        }
```

Comment: Hola, veo que en muchas de tus preguntas pones: *disculpen los errores, pero estoy comenzando*. En mi opinión no hace falta, podemos entender que estés comenzando y los errores son parte natural del proceso de aprendizaje. Considero que no deberías pedir disculpas por errores cometidos, todos los cometemos. Saludos

Comment: Gracias @MauricioContreras y viniendo de usted con su conocimiento es muy bien recibido, un gran saludo y gracias nuevamente,,,

Comment: acabo de ver que elimino el resultado de la ultima promesa "res.status(200).json({ message: "ok" })" y coloco un console.log  no sale el error pero no se como al finalizar mandar un mensaje de exito...

Comment: Estoy redactando una respuesta, pero me intriga mucho la forma en que estás haciendo las cosas. ¿Crees que podrías explicar un poco más la finalidad del `reduce` a tu lista y lo que deseas obtener? De antemano te digo que hay mucho por corregir. Saludos

Comment: si, es una lista con varios usuarios que llama un metodo que hace varias actualizaciones en varias colecciones, que hace ejecución de varias actualizaciones a varias colecciones, creo que alli puede estar el problema..de antemano gracias por su tiempo y su valiosa colaboracion, que Dios se lo retribuya en mucha salud ...